# How to zoom a selected area of image like pupil meter?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have to show in zoom of a selected area of image continuously. Means if you are changing position simultaneously zoom also to be change. I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384162/uiscrollview-zoomtorect-not-zooming-to-given-rect-created-from-uitouch-cgpoint refer this for zooming

Comment: A link-only answer has been provided below, which [points to this site](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ssuiviewminime). It may be deleted by the Review Queue, so I am preserving it here.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` has a great method - `zoomToRect:animated:` - that allows you to zoom on a specific rect. If you have a `UIImageView` sitting on a `UIScrollView` then you can zoom around the image view using this one simple method.

Comment: Hi..If we change the position in image simultaneously that zoom position also to be change....

Comment: So move the zoom position whenever the pupil position changes. That should be pretty straightforward.